# JSON Exception: No Value For

Tags: java, android, json, exception, mobile

I am writing a simple android app which uses an API to fetch some data however I am getting the following error:

```
 System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for genre_ids
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp.Networking.onPostExecute(Networking.java:72)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp.Networking.onPostExecute(Networking.java:21)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
 07-19 18:12:08.164 24204-24204/com.adeel.android.movieinfoapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Below is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonStrings = jsonObject.getJSONArray("genre_ids");
        String strings[] = new String[jsonStrings.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++) {
            strings[i] = jsonStrings.getString(i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onPostExecute(s);
}
```

}

The app I am trying to write uses this [JSON](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/35/movies?api_key=f1d314280284e94ff7d1feeed7d44fdf&language=en-US&include_adult=false&sort_by=created_at.asc).

Answer (score 2):

You are not parsing the Nested `JsonArray` properly..

Here `genre_ids` array is under the `results` array

use the following code:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);  //string pass to your onPostExecute()
    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
    for(int j=0;i<result.length;j++) {
        JSONObject inner = result.getJSONObject(j);
        JSONArray jsonStrings = inner.getJSONArray("genre_ids");
        String strings[] = new String[jsonStrings.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++) {
            strings[i] = jsonStrings.getString(i);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Added to rafsanahmad007 point, instead of "get" if you use "opt" you can get null value instead of exception

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONArray resultArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("results");

    if (resultArray == null) {
        Log.d("MM", "Json array is null");

        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject resultObj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);

        if (resultObj == null) {
            continue;
        }

        JSONArray jsonStrings = jsonObject.optJSONArray("genre_ids");

        if (jsonStrings != null) {
            String strings[] = new String[jsonStrings.length()];

            for (int j = 0; j < strings.length; j++) {
                strings[j] = jsonStrings.optString(j);
            }
        }

    }


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```